# prevent double tap on android WebView from reaching html but let tap reach html

Tags: android, kotlin, touch-event

I'm trying to create a hybrid app using android webView. 
Here is my problem:
 I have a webView and a touchListener on webView. I want tap events go down to html but prevent 
doubleTap from reaching html which is inside webview.
and this is my code:

```
webView.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
    //returning true here prevents all kind of touches from reaching html
    true
 }
```

above code prevents all touches from reaching html.
I want something like this:

```
webView.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
        if (doubleTap) {
            //return true and prevent doubleTap from reaching html
            true
        } else (!doubleTap) {
            //return false and let html recieve tap or any other gesture!
            false
        }
    }
```

By the way, I don't want to handle this with JavaScript or anything inside my html page!
(tell my if the code is very short and you need more information)
Thank You All!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to identify double taps when they occur, I would suggest you use the [GestureDetector](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector).

It has a specific listener for double taps called ***GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener***.

An example of how to use the GestureDetector is below (taken from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector)):

```
class MainActivity :
    Activity(),
    GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
    GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {

private lateinit var mDetector: GestureDetectorCompat

// Called when the activity is first created.
public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    // Instantiate the gesture detector with the
    // application context and an implementation of
    // GestureDetector.OnGestureListener
    mDetector = GestureDetectorCompat(this, this)
    // Set the gesture detector as the double tap
    // listener.
    mDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this)
}

override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    return if (mDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
        true
    } else {
        super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }
}

override fun onLongPress(event: MotionEvent) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onLongPress: $event")
}


override fun onDoubleTap(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {  // <----
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDoubleTap: $event")
    return true
}

override fun onDoubleTapEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {  // <-----
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDoubleTapEvent: $event")
    return true
  }

}
```